# Instagram api get feed between 2 dates

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to get the posts of the logged in user between 2 dates.
I noticed that there is the `users/self/media/recent` endpoint, but it seems that you can not specify a time-range.

So how can I get users posts between min_date and max_date?

Thanks,
Catalin

Answer (score 0):

Put all posts from the user in an array/db by using the pagination. Use the date as the index and do your search there.